# Cannot find symbol class GlideApp (Android Studio 3.4.2)

Tags: android, android-glide

Using Android Studio 3.4.2, I get this error:

> Cannot find symbol class GlideApp

I have tried every solution found on forums but nothing seems to work. I have tried:

- Cleaning / Rebuilding the project -> still not working
- Invalidate Caches -> still not working
- Unflag "Only sync the active variant" on Settings -> still not working

my **MyAppGlideModule.java**:

```
package com.example.balulu.models;

import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
    // empty
}
```

**Dependencies** used:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. This error did not belong to Glide, it was related to ButterKnife library whenever we missed some view id in XML and keep calling that (wrong)id in java file has produced this issue, so please make sure to use the correct view id mentioned in XML. If you cleared view id error means, this error(GlideApp) got automatically cleared. But this view id error was displayed as last of the issue list. This way I cleared this issue.